# Python [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, linux, sockets, connection, errno

In my Python socket program, I sometimes need to interrupt it with <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. When I do this, it does close the connection using `socket.close()`.

However, when I try to reopen it I have to wait what seems like a minute before I can connect again. How does one correctly close a socket? Or is this intended?

Comment: More generally, the error message may also be seen if some other process is using that port, refer to: [python - socket.error: \[Errno 48\] Address already in use - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071512/socket-error-errno-48-address-already-in-use). ■ Also refer to [linux - How to forcibly close a socket in TIME_WAIT? - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/329845/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-time-wait) for solutions that works when you "forgot" to set REUSEADDR in your program.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Yes, this is intended. Here you can read a [detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337115/setting-time-wait-tcp). It is possible to override this behavior by setting the `SO_REUSEADDR` option on a socket. For example:

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Comment: Strange. I've called this right before binding and the error is still occurring. I must be making a mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Nevermind, I had a bizarre race condition when repeatedly binding and shutting down on separate threads for my automated tests.

Comment: You need to import module called socket.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` works, BUT you should use that right after you create the socket. It will not work after `.bind()`!

Comment: where do you set this?  Inside python? bash?

Comment: @thistleknot No, in your code. For example: 
       `udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, / socket.SOCK_DGRAM) / udp.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)) / udp.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`
(/ is a new line)

Comment: solution does not work for me.

Comment: @Alex, can you elaborate and post the code?

Comment: @Bartosz I will post the code when I encounter this issue again.

Answer (score 65):

```
$ ps -fA | grep python
501 81211 12368   0  10:11PM ttys000    0:03.12  
python -m SimpleHTTPServer

$ kill 81211
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't always work. This was my immediate thought when I ran into this problem, but there is no python process to kill in my case.

Comment: @Kryten use Kill -9 81211

Comment: [Do not use kill -9](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8916/when-should-i-not-kill-9-a-process).  It wouldn't work in this case anyway as the user stated that there is no python process to kill.

Answer (score 54):

This happens because you trying to run service at the same port and there is an already running application.
it can happen because your service is not stopped in the process stack. you just have to kill those processes.

***There is no need to install anything*** here is the one line command to kill all running python processes.

**for Linux based OS:**

Bash:

```
kill -9 $(ps -A | grep python | awk '{print $1}')
```

Fish:

```
kill -9 (ps -A | grep python | awk '{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 27):

If you use a `TCPServer`, `UDPServer` or their subclasses in the `socketserver` module, you can set this class variable (before instantiating a server):

```
socketserver.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
```

(via [SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer - Cannot bind to address after program restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274320/socketserver-threadingtcpserver-cannot-bind-to-address-after-program-restart) )

This causes the **init** (constructor) to:

```
 if self.allow_reuse_address:
     self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

Comment: where do you set this?  Inside python? bash?

Comment: [According to the documentation this is not recommended, recommended method is to subclass.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.allow_reuse_address)

Answer (score 16):

A simple solution that worked for me is to close the Terminal and restart it.

Answer (score 14):

Nothing worked for me except running a subprocess with this command, before calling `HTTPServer(('', 443), myHandler)`:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -ti tcp:443)
```

Of course this is only for linux-like OS!

Answer (score 12):

For Linux,

`ps aux | grep python`

This will show you the error. The process number (eg.35225) containing your python file is the error.

Now,

`sudo kill -9 35225`

This will kill the error process and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 8):

First of all find the python process ID using this command

```
ps -fA | grep python
```

You will get a pid number by naming of your python process on **second column**

Then kill the process using this command

```
kill -9 pid
```

Answer (score 3):

run the command

```
fuser -k (port_number_you_are _trying_to_access)/TCP
```

example for flask:   `fuser -k 5000/tcp`

Also, remember this error arises when you interput by ctrl+z. so to terminate use ctrl+c

Comment: This doesn't quite work if the process that used that port is already dead :q

Comment: **NOTE** you need lowercase `tcp` instead of `TCP`!

Answer (score 3):

Do nothing just wait for a couple of minutes and it will get resolved. It happens due to the slow termination of some processes, and that's why it's not even showing in the running processes list.

Comment: I think this is true, but it doesn't help to know this.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar error at odoo server and resolved that with these simple following steps:

1. Paste following code in terminal

   ps -fA | grep python

You will get a pid number. Now copy the pid number from second column of terminal output.

2. Then write as below

   kill -9 pid

The terminal will restart and then the command

```
flask run
```

Will work fine!
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Err98 Address already in use) on a Raspberry Pi running python for a EV charging manager for a Tesla Wall Connector. The software had previously been fine but it stopped interrogating the solar inverter one day and I spent days thinking it was something I'd done in python. Turns out the root cause was the Wifi modem assigning a new dynamic IP to the solar inverter as as result of introducing a new smart TV into my home. I changed the python code to reflect the new IP address that I found from the wifi modem and bingo, the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to make the socket *immediately* reusable is to follow the recommendation to first shutdown the client end (*socket*) of a connection, and make sure the server's end shuts down last (through exception handling if needed).

**This might well mean that the server end runs forever.**

This is not a problem if that "forever" loop *pauses execution*, e.g. read from socket.

How you "break" that "forever" loop is up to you as server admin, as long as there are no clients (apart from obvious system level exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code to settle the issue:

```
sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

in Terminal

Check PID of program:

```
$ netstat -tulpn

# output:

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
                   
#...
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:20001         0.0.0.0:*                           2859/python
```

in this case **port: 20001**, so **PID is 2859**

terminate this port:

```
$ kill -9 2859
```

Answer (score -3):

sudo pkill -9 python

try this command

Comment: Despite this being technically a possible solution to the problem here, I don't think this is a good idea to simply kill all python processes. What if you have some other processes that need python to work properly? You would kill all of them.