# A simple python server using SimpleHTTPServer and SocketServer, how do I close the socket down before rerunning .py file?

Tags: python, http, sockets, networking

When I run my python server file `simplehttpwebsite.py` in the linux shell and I do control+c and run it again I get `socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`.

How do I  make sure the socket closes down when I do ctrl+c?

*simplehttpwebsite.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
server = SocketServer.TCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use

Comment: @freakish: same cause yes, but different solution within the `SocketServer` framework

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is how you do it

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
class MyTCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
server = MyTCPServer(('0.0.0.0', 8080), Handler)

server.serve_forever()
```

IMHO this isn't very well documented, and it should definitely be the default.