# Python TCPServer, error 98, Address already in use

Tags: python, sockets, tcpserver

I faced error 98, address already in use problem while I kill an running python TCPServer server and try to re-start it.

I noticed there is other [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use), suggest to sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  or set TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True.

But I still faced the same problem, is there any other reason for this?

I am using RedHat EL 6.2, Python 2.6.

Thanks

The code I used was:

```
TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
TCPServer.__init__(self, (gethostname(), self.SERVER_PORT),scheddRequestHandler)
```

This keeps on getting me the error 98.

However if I changed to:

```
TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
TCPServer((gethostname(),self.SERVER_PORT),scheddRequestHandler)
```

The error is gone.

I am not quite clear why this happened?

Comment: Are you killing sockets in a non clean manner? It could be leaving behind resources that would temporarily prevent a reconnection. As Mike said, show code