# SocketServer: getting rid of '[Errno 98] Address already in use'

Tags: python, python-2.7, socketserver

I've been looking at the documentation for [`SocketServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html). I copied the TCP server code from the documentation and it runs fine. However, I noticed that whenever I ctrl-c'ed out of the program in my terminal, and then tried to run it again, I would get the following error:

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I looked into how to remedy the problem by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337115/setting-time-wait-tcp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use). I added the following line to my code to try to allow reuse of the address:

```
server.allow_reuse_address = True
```

I am still experiencing the same problem even with the above line added. I also added a `try` and `except` around my `server.serve_forever()` function, catching the KeyboardInterrupt exception and calling `server.shutdown()` and `server.socket.close()` in hopes that the address would be freed.

Here is the full extent of my TCP server code (Note: I excluded the MyTCPHandler class):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = '', 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    try:
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.shutdown()
        server.socket.close()
```

I am still getting the error running the code above and have to wait close to a minute until the address is finally freed. This is frustrating when I'm debugging and changing my code constantly.

I'm running this code using Python 2.7.3 on a RaspberryPi running Raspbian "Wheezy" 7.0.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
...
SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
...
```

`allow_reuse_address` should be on the class, not on the instance.