# python socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, python-2.7

when i setup application.py, it shows that socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "application.py", line 121, in <module>
main()
File "application.py", line 117, in main
http_server.listen(options.port)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 117, in listen
sockets = bind_sockets(port, address=address)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado-3.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/netutil.py", line 90, in bind_sockets
sock.bind(sockaddr)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the application.

Comment: If you know the address it is trying to use, then you can find out what else is holding that address with `netstat`.

Comment: Change the `address` and provide us more code please.

Comment: @emuu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465959/python-errno-98-address-already-in-use

Comment: ```sudo lsof -t -i tcp:8000 | xargs kill -9```

Comment: What is 'application.py' exactly?

Comment: I'm coding another server app and the same trouble happened.
If you want to restart your server immediately and listen on the port you should set the REUSE flag as here
`s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)`
I executed `netstat -e -an | grep 1089` command and found out that the connection had not closed. It was alive in FIN_WAIT2 state
The socket was shutdown, but not closed yet. The socket stayed in FIN_WAIT2 state.
You may check it yourself try to start the app, kill the app, and check connections.

Comment: killing is the best way to get ride of this problem.

Comment: Another process is listen on the port on a bash shell try `kill -9 $(ps -A | grep python | awk '{print $1}')` . For additional details check out https://www.janbasktraining.com/community/sql-server/python-socketerror-errno-98-address-already-in-use1

Answer (score 165):

There is obviously another process listening on the port. You might find out that process by using the following command:

```
$ lsof -i :8000
```

or change your tornado app's port. tornado's error info not **Explicitly** on this.

Comment: Me too :D
And, it's not possible to use that solution, @NeDark, in every case.

Comment: This is working for me to check what program is using that address

Comment: This answer didn't work under my case where a socket is created by Python application and th application is forced exit. Please follow the link and see the answer by ayoub laaziz

Comment: Worked for me with `sudo` and port 5000 (for a Flask app), e.g. `sudo lsof -i :5000` to detect the process listening on the port, and then `sudo kill -9 <process_id>`

Comment: +1 It is in any case helpful to "rule out" this particular cause of the problem, and in general a very helpful thing to know about.

Comment: Nothing shows up after I execute this command (even `sudo lsof -i :8000`), but still I am getting the same error. :(

Comment: @ytu Try `sudo lsof -i | grep "py"`.

Comment: I am using sudo didnt show anything op.

Comment: For those facing this issue with nothing coming up from `netstat` or `lsof`, if you are testing/restarting a script that makes a call to [`socket.bind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind), you may find that the address may still be in use for a while even after killing the involved process : checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4466035/2529954).

Comment: Is there an equivalent command for ubuntu?