# Errno 98 Address already in use when auto script starts at reboot

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, autorun

I want to start a python server when raspberry pi reboots. I have written in this file `sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc` my python3 command to start the .py script, but every time raspberry pi reboots the terminal shows me:

```
[Errno 98] Address already in use.
```

When I run `pgrep` python3, it shows that I already have a python process running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python socket.error: \[Errno 98\] Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17780291/python-socket-error-errno-98-address-already-in-use)

Answer (score 0):

There are two python processes attempting to use the same port. You have to change the configuration of either one of them to use a different port so both of them can start. How you do this depends on your exact invocation, for illustration look at this flask invocation:

```
flask run --port=5001
```